# Mad Libs ATBS with Python using regular expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on the "Mad Libs" project in ATBS. The program should read in text files and allow the user to add their own text anywhere 'ADJECTIVE', 'NOUN', 'ADVERB' or 'VERB' appears in the text file.

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
    import os, re

    NewFile=input('Please enter the path of the file to be used:')
    NewFilepath=os.path.abspath(NewFile)
    print(NewFilepath)
    if os.path.exists(NewFilepath)==True: 
        open(NewFile, 'a')
    else: 
        print('This file does not exist. Creating a new file.')
        open(NewFile, 'w')

    NewFileContent=NewFile.read()

    def NewMadLibs(): 
        SpeechParts=re.compile(r'ADJECTIVE|NOUN|ADVERB|VERB', re.I)
        match=re.findall(NewFileContent)
        for match in NewFileContent: 
            if match=='ADJECTIVE': 
                adjective=input('Enter an adjective:\n')
            SpeechParts.sub(adjective, 'ADJECTIVE')
            if match=='NOUN': 
                noun=input('Enter a noun:\n')
            SpeechParts.sub(noun, 'NOUN')
            if match=='ADVERB': 
                adverb=input('Enter an adverb:\n')
            SpeechParts.sub(adverb, 'ADVERB')
            if match=='VERB': 
                verb=input('Enter a verb:\n')
            SpeechParts.sub(verb, 'VERB')

    NewMadLibs(NewFileContent)
    UserMadLibsFile=NewFileContent.read()
    print(UserMadLibsFile)
    new_FileName='new_'+'source.txt'
    new_file=open(new_FileName, 'w')
    new_file.write(UserMadLibsFile)
    new_file.close()
    print("The file is saved as 'new_source.txt'")
```

The error message that appears looks like this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/myname/Documents/MadLibsNewTry.py", line 16, in <module>
    NewFileContent=NewFile.read()
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I'm confused by this error because I'm opening up the NewFile in either append mode or write mode depending on if the file (path) already exists. Shouldn't that  create or open "NewFile" and it would be a file object, not a string? The code didn't get to this point, but I figured that a similar error would occur for the line: UserMadLibsFile=NewFileContent.read() in the final block.

I'm open to any suggestions or other methods that I should consider for this practice problem.

Comment: You need to save the file object returned by `open()` and use that for file I/O, like at the bottom of the code with `new_file`. Calling `open()` doesn't change `NewFile` from a string to a file object.

Comment: @sj95126 Thank you so much. I see the mistake and I realize that I forgot to save the file returned by `open()` in a variable just like I did for `new_file`.  However, I'm having another issue in which the code won't read the text file that I enter when asked for the path of the file. I'll probably have to edit my post to get some suggestions on how to fix that error.